# Ubuntu 18 / RPI 4: No USB Storage in initrd

Tags: boot, usb, updates

I just updated my Ubuntu 18 in a Raspberry pi 4. And USB devices are not detected in the initrd phase.

I can see that `initramfs.conf` sets `MODULES=most` and that usb-storage and uas modules are present.

Even if I load them by hand from the initrd shell (dropbear) no USB devices are detected:

```
[ 1154.045506] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[ 1154.050243] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
```

When the typical output would be this one:

```
[27568553.887498] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[27568553.908456] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000, bcdDevice=11.00
[27568553.908474] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[27568553.908486] usb 2-2: Product: Flash Drive FIT
[27568553.908497] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Samsung
[27568553.908508] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 0315218100002339
[27568554.092407] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[27568554.092750] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: Quirks match for vid 090c pid 1000: 400
[27568554.092867] scsi host0: usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[27568554.093300] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[27568554.101372] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[27568555.400291] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Samsung  Flash Drive FIT  1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[27568555.401496] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[27568555.402145] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 125313283 512-byte logical blocks: (64.2 GB/59.8 GiB)
[27568555.402372] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[27568555.402386] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[27568555.402614] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[27568555.424179] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

This update has disabled something in the kernel/initrd but I have no clue what.

Any idea?

Comment: There is no such version of Ubuntu as 18

Comment: here David: https://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/